# Fanatic badge on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, badges, meta, activity-badges

I just looked at the [Badges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges) on Meta Stack Overflow and the Fanatic badge is strangely absent. <strike>I suspect that it's been intentionally ommitted as the Fanatic badge [was announced](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/enthusiast-and-fanatic-badges/) before [Meta Stack Overflow went live](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/cmon-get-meta/), and Super User, which was launched after Meta Stack Overflow, [has the badge](https://superuser.com/badges/42/fanatic) (though it hasn't been awarded yet).</strike> It now sounds like this could be an oversight, since the Fanatic badge was only [added to Super User yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24748/fanatic-badge-on-meta/24751#24751).

On the one hand, as a user that would be a recipient of the gold badge I'm inclined to request that it be added, but at the same time I can understand that Meta Stack Overflow has a different dynamic than the rest of the sites. It's obvious who the daily contributors are, so the existence of the badge might be redundant.

Should Meta have a Fanatic badge, or is the Enthusiast badge enough?

**P.S.**: I'm not posting this for purely theoretical reasons - today would have been the day that the badges would have been awarded.

Comment: Finally implemented!

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing because ["meta means murder"](https://web.archive.org/web/20100126025309/http://www.codinghorror.com:80/blog/archives/001282.html), and Jeff doesn't want to encourage us *too* much, even if we are off on a different site ;-p

[image]
<sub>(source: [typepad.com](https://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0120a86e1d35970b-pi))</sub>

Comment: My excuse is that the ♦ needs it - so what are you *losers* doing here? `<g>`

Comment: I saw the door open and entered. Now I can't get out.

Comment: @voyager: Welcome to the Hotel California.

Comment: You can check out, but never leave

Comment: Better to check out than to commit. Oh, you're not talking about source repositories?

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to `http://www.codinghorror.com/`.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum feel free to fix it, I guess?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the implication is that those of us who spend a lot of time on meta are proving our fanaticism to such a great extent, that the badge would serve no further purpose.

Comment: Geddouofhere with your talk of no need for badges. A badge is a badge is a want another badge.

Comment: @random, agreed, I want it as well, just hazarding a guess.

Answer (score 2):

I guess no one wants to show that we don't have a life.

Comment: Oh good, finally out of hiding.

Answer (score 2):

It was only just [added to Super User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24589/does-the-disciplined-badge-work-on-superuser/24591#24591). I guess it is a manual configuration per site, and as [random says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24748/fanatic-badge-on-meta-stack-overflow/24750#comment107971_24749), it shows you don't have a life.

Comment: Since when did anyone need evidence?

Comment: Thanks for finding this, I've updated my post :-)

Comment: Said what when?

Comment: It just sounds like a familiar random quote, not sure where it was mentioned though. Head scratcher.

Comment: @random I thought you had answered this question just before me with that sentiment. The answer is no longer visible to my low-rep eyes so I can't tell if you're messing with me or I have got you mixed up with another answererer

Comment: Not on this question at least. Probably on another though.

Answer (score 0):

The Woot badge is on all sites - I thought Fanatic was, too.. but alas, it is not.