# Top ten signs that your coworker is using Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, meta, fun

How can you tell if one of your coworkers has been secretly using Meta Stack Overflow in their free time?

Comment: Is it Friday where you are already?

Comment: @user I lost track of the days in my cave, so I'm hoping so

Comment: @user: It's Friday somewhere!

Comment: WTF is free time?

Comment: @squillman: Meta time

Comment: It's Friday here

Answer (score 38, accepted):

They stopped posting on Stack Overflow, and now seem to be getting even *less* work done.

Answer (score 33):

He says "You should totally drop that and use jQuery" in completely inappropriate situations. example

> Employee A: Dude, me and my wife got
> into this big fight last night.
>
> Employee B: You should totally drop
> her and try jQuery

Comment: +1 Extremely unfunny

Comment: +1 - extremely practical. I tried that today and it worked!

Comment: There's probably a plugin for that...lemme check

Comment: I'd like to point out that since 1.4 dropped the easiest way to say "you should totally drop that and use jQuery" in completely inappropriate situations is to use the new $.live() functionality.

Comment: Can you send me the code for that?

Answer (score 24):

Every estimate is now 6 - 8 weeks, and he wants to do the work from a boat.

Answer (score 20):

- They have a newly-developed unicorn and/or waffle obsession.
- They start insisting that it's Friday somewhere, even when it isn't.
- They begin demanding that freehand circles be drawn around everything.

Comment: It is in iceland. While they were off partying, they let a volcano go off, and now all our flights are cancelled :(

Answer (score 14):

They write [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) next to everything.

Comment: more like `status-declined` :P

Comment: Okay... fine. That too.

Comment: @Johannes, some, like me, actually think it looks worse.

Comment: @Arjan Thought it gets the nice red color.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Now with nice red colour.

Comment: @michaelb958 ohh, thanks. Forgot the `meta-` part \*hides\*

Answer (score 13):

They write in haiku,
Expecting people's upvotes.
Whatever that means.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32509/has-stack-overflow-been-haiku-hacked/32853#32853

Comment: You didn't write your answer as a haiku, so don't expect an upvote.

Comment: Much better now. +1

Answer (score 8):

- Instead of playing an april fool's joke, they just replaced all the pictures in your office with unicorns.
- They complain your charts are useless because the circles were computer-aided.

Answer (score 8):

The website on their screen is the most awkward combination of grey and maroon.

Comment: and yes, it is always on their screen.

Answer (score 7):

- they suddenly burst out laughing unexpectedly and cry, "waffles, OF COURSE!"
- you see them spending an inordinate amount of time in Microsoft Paint trying to perfect their freehand circles.
- they have a google image search up with a lot of waffle and pony pictures standing ready

Comment: I would say my practice time is perfectly ordinate. Freehand circles is hard!

Answer (score 7):

He is wearing a meta T-shirt.

[image]

Comment: I **want** that

Comment: @earlz <waves hand> no you don't.

Answer (score 5):

He complains about exceeding his disk quota, and when you investigate to find out why, it turns out that it's because he has 38 GB of unicorn pictures saved.

Comment: Hopefully it's not *uniporn*!

Comment: @gnovice: That would be one of the top ten signs that your coworker needs professional help.  Wait... that's the same as being on Meta, never mind.

Answer (score 3):

They have started saying "*Eeek*!" a lot.

Answer (score 1):

They start replying to emails or other correspondence with:

**+1 excellent idea!**

But most importantly, they have already read this thread. Most likely they will ask something elusive, such as:

*"If the top 10 of something have 15 answers, shouldn't it be the top 15?"*

Answer (score 0):

[He isn't available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24748/fanatic-badge-on-meta#comment-51744).

Answer (score 0):

Every solution becomes just a greasemonkey script away.

Answer (score -1):

He'll give you humorous questions/answers/comments that are completely off-topic, and later excuse himself because it's not Friday yet.

Comment: Lies, its always friday somewhere

Answer (score -1):

They start making snide comments every time you ask a question unless that's their normal behavior.  If that is their normal behavior, then check whether the comments include references to waffles, ponies, or He Who Must Not Be Named.

Comment: We never make snide comments. Never ever! Well, more ever than never, but I think even you will get it...

Comment: Snide what? How dare you! Liar! Cheater! Deceiver! :)

Answer (score -1):

They come to work wearing breakfast foods on their heads.  They keep pets in their cubicles that also, inexplicably, wear breakfast foods on their heads.

<sub>better than prosthetic foreheads, i suppose.</sub>

Comment: where was i? i forgot the point that i was making.  i said if i was smart that i would save up for a piece of string and a rock to wind the string around