# cannot de-favorite a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, bookmarks

I get this error:

> An error has occurred - please retry
>   your request. (click on this box to
>   dismiss)

Comment: Has the question been "de-favourited" after a page refresh? I sometimes get that message on voting, but when I double check the vote has been registered.

Comment: Browser? OS? Browser version? OS version? Constellation of Jupiter and Saturn?

Comment: You can check out, but you can never leave.

Comment: I thought that [Meta was the Hotel California](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24748/fanatic-badge-on-meta/24750#24750)

Comment: @perbert Meta is the top floor of the hotel (the one even the song doesn't dare mention.)

Answer (score 4):

A css class changed, causing the jQuery selector on that specific page to fail finding the question id.

Fixed and will be deployed this evening.

Answer (score 1):

edit: yes, I understand now and can reproduce this... it's specific to the user page on the favorites tab.

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox, IE, Chrome and Safari. I think this might be a server error. When I click on the star firebug shows a POST to http://stackoverflow.com/posts/undefined/vote/5 , 'undefined' looks like a js bug.